# Fill the stream with exact amount of bytes in C++

Tags: c++, string, stream, fill

I've got a stream which I need to fill up to an exact size (`const size_t bytes`) with a text (`const char * filler = "Something"`) multiple times until it reaches the size of bytes.

Like this: *SomethingSomethingSomething* or *SomethingSome*, if there is no more available byte, then it can be truncated but it always has to be that exact size.
e.g. bytes are 30

```
    const size_t bytes = 30;
    const char * text = "Something";

    int x = bytes / strlen(text);

    for (int j = 0; j < x; j++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < strlen(text); i++)
        {
            stream << text[i];
        }
    }
```

Like this above I only can fill the stream with not truncated words instead of: *SomethingSomethingSomethingSom* (this is exactly 30)

How can I rework this code? Thank you!

Comment: What is the problem with the code you show? How do you want to "rework" it? What is the actual *and expected* contents of the stream?

Comment: currently: SomethingSomethingSomethingSomething (length is 36), expected: SomethingSomethingSomethingSom (length is 30)

Comment: As an alternative to the answer posted below, with your current code you could add a check to make sure that `j * x + i` won't be larger than `bytes` in your inner loop.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`write()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/write) function to put data to `std::ostream`. Repeat this to get the desired number of bytes.

```cpp
    const size_t bytes = 30;
    const char * text = "Something";
    size_t textLen = strlen(text);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < bytes / textLen; i++)
    {
        stream.write(text, textLen);
    }
    stream.write(text, bytes % textLen);
```

Or simply put each characters to the stream:

```cpp
    const size_t bytes = 30;
    const char * text = "Something";
    size_t textLen = strlen(text);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < bytes; i++)
    {
        stream << text[i % textLen];
    }
```

Comment: Thanks but this custom defined stream does not work this way with "write" unfortunately :(

Comment: @chuck Then simply put each character: `for (size_t i = 0; i < bytes; i++) stream << text[i % textLen];`

Comment: Thank you for the useful and quick answer! This helped! I am a beginner but it is nice to have some people who can show different solutions!